# Convert pixel location to latitude/longitude & vise versa

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript-3, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I need to convert latitude longitude values into pixel positions as well as do the opposite. I've found many solutions to go from lat/lng->pixel, but can't find anything on the reverse.

A couple of notes:

- The map is a fixed size, no zooming, no tiles.
- I don't need anything super accurate, its not important.
- Preferably mercator projection, but not required. I'm not actually display the result. (Any 2D projection)
- I can't rely on any web based API's, ie: no Google Maps

A solution in almost any programming language would be fine, as long as it doesn't rely on any platform specific APIs.

This is an example of going from lat/lng->pixel:

```
var y = Math.round(((-1 * lat) + 90) * (this.MAP_HEIGHT / 180));
var x = Math.round((lng + 180) * (this.MAP_WIDTH / 360));
```

Comment: You need to know which map projection the computation must work for. The example computation in your question will _not_ work for a Mercator map; it assumes an [equirectangular projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection).

Comment: I'm open to any 2D projection, equirectangular will meet my needs perfectly. I'm not visualizing the result, so I'm not tied to a specific projection.

Comment: If you are not displaying anything, then what on earth (!) are you using pixels for in the first place?

Comment: Doing some server side stuff that needs to translate lat/lng to a 2D plane, it eventually gets converted back to lat/lng before it gets visualized client side. Pixels is not a very accurate word for the problem, but helped me to express what I needed.

Comment: But (latitude,longitude) _already_ constitutes 2D coordinates. You can call it "pixels" in your head (x=longitude, y=latitude) without changing them in any way, if that will help you visualize a computation.

Comment: I needed to work with whole numbers for my particular solution. I don't doubt there are ways of accomplishing my goal without the conversion, (they're probably better), but that's the one I came up with.

Comment: What unit is MAP_HEIGHT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var y = Math.round(((-1 * lat) + 90) * (this.MAP_HEIGHT / 180));
var x = Math.round((lng + 180) * (this.MAP_WIDTH / 360));
```

Use some algebra and I came out with:

```
var lat=(y/(this.MAP_HEIGHT/180)-90)/-1
var lng = x/(this.MAP_WIDTH/360)-180
```

Not completely confident in that math since it was done in my head, but those should work, just make sure to test them first.

Comment: It might be obvious, by my math skills are rusty. Thanks so much, just what I needed!

Comment: What are the numbers though? 180, 360 etc? also Map_height is in degrees or pixels?

Comment: Would also like to know the answer to John's comment