# Finding lat/long within a images using image metadata

Tags: python, geolocation, gps, mapping, orthographic

I'm using Pix4dx Capture Pro and Parrot Anafi to map a large field that contains farm equipment.  I would like the lat/log of the farm equipment within the images. I have all the drone variables to compute the locations.  However, I don't know how to determine Pix4dx map variables:  map size, projection reference, etc.

Given that I can easily obtain the farm equipment's x  and y pixel locations, I plan to use the following equations to determine lat/long.

```py
var lat=(y/(this.MAP_HEIGHT/180)-90)/-1

var lng = x/(this.MAP_WIDTH/360)-180
```

But I don't know if the equations are valid due to unknown Pix4dx projection reference. Any help with Pix4dx map details would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

lat/long equations ref: [Convert pixel location to latitude/longitude & vise versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019101/convert-pixel-location-to-latitude-longitude-vise-versa)

Comment: Since this is more of a conceptual GIS question, maybe https://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be more helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I will review and possibly post there, too.